# How to show a value from raw_id_fields in django?

Tags: django

I need to get a value from foreign key which is the url that I plan to display using javascript. The problem is after creating this:

```
class SplashScreenAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'text', 'background', 'button', )
    search_fields = ('title', 'text')
    list_filter = ('background', 'button')
    raw_id_fields = ('picture',)

admin.site.register(SplashScreen, SplashScreenAdmin)
```

I cannot get the data from it. At the very least I need it to show the caption right beside the raw_id_fields. Is there any easy way to achieve this?

[image: What I need to do]

Comment: Have you tried specifying the ```help_text``` parameter on the field? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#help-text

Comment: I want the get the caption from the data model too. So, if it's picture I can get the picture name or picture url. I don't think help_text can retrieve object data.

Comment: You're right. That's my mistake. You'll have to look into customizing a form field to do what you're looking for.

Comment: Finally able to make this work with some hacks in javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a little hacks in here and there I finally able to get this to work.

Models.py

```
class ImageMedia(models.Model):
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='image_media', blank=True)

class SplashScreen(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    text = models.TextField()
    background = models.ForeignKey(Background)
    button = models.ForeignKey(Button)
    url = models.URLField()
    picture = models.ForeignKey(ImageMedia)

    def splash_image(self):
        return '<img id="media_image" src="{0}{1}" height="150px"/><p id="media_caption">Caption</p> '.format(
            settings.MEDIA_URL, '')

    splash_image.allow_tags = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
import json

@login_required
def get_picture_media(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        media_id = request.GET['media_id']

        if media_id:
            media = ImageMedia.objects.get(id=int(media_id))
            if media:
                media_data = {'media_url': media.picture.url, 'media_caption': media.caption}
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(media_data))
```

Admin.py

```
class SplashScreenAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'text', 'background', 'button', )
    search_fields = ('title', 'text')
    list_filter = ('background', 'button')
    raw_id_fields = ('picture',)
    fields = ('title', 'text', 'background', 'button', 'url', 'picture', 'splash_image')
    readonly_fields = ['splash_image']

    class Media:
        js = ("js/media-render.js",)

admin.site.register(SplashScreen, SplashScreenAdmin)
```

js/media-render.js

```
function media_render() {
    var id_picture = document.getElementById('id_picture').value;
                    var media_url = '';
                    var media_caption = '';
                    $.get(document.location.origin + '/get_picture_media/', {media_id: id_picture},
                                        function(data){
                                            data = JSON.parse(data);
                                            media_url = data['media_url'];
                                            media_caption = data['media_caption'];
                                            document.getElementById('media_image').src = media_url;
                                            document.getElementById('media_caption').innerHTML = media_caption;});
                    };
window.onfocus = media_render;
document.getElementById('id_picture').onchange = media_render;
```

This way I can always update my image whenever I change the raw ID and I also get the caption. With schillingt I separate the js a little bit so the code are now a little bit neater

Final Result:

[image: Final result]

Comment: You could add the javascript to it's own JS file and include it via the media files option on the admin.

Comment: Isn't adding it to option will make it active in the whole admin site? If not is there any links for the example or the documentation, I might try to implement it.

Comment: Nope, it'll only be used on that Model's create and update pages. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-asset-definitions

Comment: You are right, I've tweaked the code so it looks neater now thanks to you.